# Can a Maven plugin use build dependencies?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have a custom maven plugin that runs in the process-classes phase. It needs to load and reflect over the class files generated by the build, but this means explicitly re-declaring all the dependencies in the plugin setup.

Is it possible for a plugin to inherit build dependencies?

**Some further context:**

The plugin in question processes classes generated by the compile phase, spitting out an equivalent representation to each class in a different language (i.e. it's basically a java transpiler).

To achieve this end, the plugin needs to reflect over the process classes. This works fine so long as the plugin has the same dependencies as the classes themselves. Otherwise you get reflection errors when the classes or class methods load and reference a type not included in the plugin classpath (Note that due to some third party issues, simply inspecting the classfile binaries using something like ASM would not be sufficient).

**Example POM:**

```
<project>
  <!-- ...boilerplate... -->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>myplugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-custom-plugin-that-processes-classes</artifactId>

      <!-- To process classes generated by the main build, I need to
           duplicate dependencies or I'll get reflection issues.
           For example if a class in my code 'X' uses a static
           SLF4J logger, I will get a clinit error when I load
           X for processing unless I include this. -->
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>

    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please elaborate more in detail what kind of problem you are trying to solve...best would be examples of POM files and classes etc.

Comment: If you get reflection errors means you are not going the right way cause there is a difference between the plugin dependencies which are separated from the project dependencies...without the code the plugin I can't help here..

Answer (score 1):

I see some different ways to solve this issue that I would like to share.

**Idea 1**

You say that you're trying to load the generated files with something like `Class.forName(...)` and this fails because of the lacking dependency. Can you please share what exactly you're trying to do with the generated files? Maybe it worth analyzing the bytecode with something like ASM/JAVAASSIST. These libraries do not usually do reflection.

**Idea 2**

An another approach is as follows: 
You can get an access to all the dependencies of the pom.xml from within the plugin. So you can construct the list of dependencies to start an additional reactor process with (in-memory, right from the plugin) or alternatively create a classpath of actual jar locations and just spawn another java process with this classpath.

All-in-all I'm not aware of the way to do what you want and frankly there is a reason for this: what if your plugin is designed to use one version of dependency X and the application itself uses the same dependency of version Y. This would end up with clash of dependencies and make plugins too fragile.